# Flight-Orders Self-Service API payment options

Tags: amadeus

Question1:

I have tested Flight-Orders API which shows in beta state. Can we use this API in production and if yes, what are the payment methods to use?

Question2:

While testing self-service API's I have been able to run workflow below

1. Flight-Offers V2 (https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers)
2. Flight-Offers/Pricing using result from 1 (https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing)
3. Flight-Orders using output from 2 (https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/booking/flight-orders)

But, result from Flight Low-Fare Search (https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers) is missing fields to be used in flow above. Are results from Low-Fare results not intended to be used for any consecutive action like pricing/order?

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**:

The API is in beta because we are piloting the access in production with beta testers. We are still accepting pilots, if you are interested you can contact us at developers@amadeus.com.

After the testing phase, the production will be opened to everybody. The payment methods are the same as for the other APIS:

- Credit card payment
- Bank transfer

**Question 2**:

You are 100% right, Flight Low-fare Search is version 1 of our flight search. It will be decommissioned for Flight Offers Search (version 2 of our flight search) in the future.

And you are right about the flow:
Flight Offers Search -> Flight Offers Price -> Flight Create Orders

We will communicate more about it in the future but you can take a look at [this blog article](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/api-release-flight-offers-search-price).